# How to update item in session array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, session-variables

I need update 1 item of my session , i send a new quantity from my form, `$item['quantity']` change but not `Session::get('details_evacuation_file')`

It's the structure

```php
    Session::push('details_evacuation_file', [
                  'id' => $p_temp->id,
                  'quantity' => 1,
                  'cost' => null,
                  'discount' => 0,
                  'product' => $p_temp  
                ]);
```

My function

```php
    public function update_quantity(Request $request) {
           $details = Session::get('details_evacuation_file', []);
            foreach ($details as $item) {
                if ($item['id'] == $request->input('id')) {
                    var_dump($item['quantity']); 
                    $item['quantity'] = $request->input('quantity');
                    var_dump($request->input('quantity')); 
                    var_dump($item['quantity']);  
                }
            }
           session('details_evacuation_file', $details );
           var_dump(Session::get('details_evacuation_file'));
           die();
           return redirect()->back();
        }
```

Comment: You are not passing $item as a reference so it won't reflect on $details. Please see [this](https://www.phpreferencebook.com/samples/php-pass-by-reference/)

Comment: now $details update,  but not Session::get('details_evacuation_file')

Comment: session('details_evacuation_file', $details ); not work

Comment: Session::put('details_evacuation_file', $details ); ... it works , thanks a lot for your help :)